# Can I Share/Sync My Picasa Web Albums Automatically to My Facebook Account?

Tags: facebook, picasa-web-albums, synchronization

I use Picasa/Picasa Web to manage my photos. I would like photos I upload into Picasa web to show up automatically in my Facebook Photos section.

Requirements:

- **Fully Automatic**: When I upload photos to Picasa Web, I want them imported/viewable in Facebook without any further intervention.
- **Only Public Albums**: Nothing I have marked as private should make the transfer
- **Not Necessarily Immediate**: The transfer can be delayed a bit (no more than 1 day), but instant would be nice.
- **All Data Transferred**: Images, captions, timestamps should all be carried over.
- **Status Updates**: It would be nice if a Facebook status update can be generated whenever a new album/photo is synced - just as if I had posted it myself.
- **One Way Only**: Nothing the happens in Facebook needs to be carried back over to Picasa Web.

Comment: The solutions mentioned do not work anymore, anyone has any other solution?

Comment: Try google picasa importer...best program to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can.

Click here: http://apps.facebook.com/fotofan/

Then follow the directions to sync with your Picasa account. It will give your profile a "Picasa" tab. 
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/1b29f95865.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/1b29f95865.png)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't do status updates, but I believe that's the only way to do the link.

Comment: The fotofan app also disappeared from Facebook unfortunately...

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered another way that also seems to update your wall automatically when you post new photos. On your Facebook wall there is a button "Options" below the status update box. Clicking on this will reveal another button "Setting". There you can add your Picasa site.

Uploading a picture to my Picasa account automatically triggered an update on my wall. However, unlike the built in Facebook photos, no album is created to view previous pictures although friends can still comment on your wall post.

[image]

**Edit** Well isn't Facebook annoying. Literally the day after I post this, the feature has been removed with the following notice:

> The Imported Stories feature is no
>   longer available. Most of the sites
>   supported by this feature now allow
>   you to publish stories to Facebook
>   directly from the site.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Windows app called "Social Folders" that is very close to doing it. The only problem is that it has separate folders for each service (ie one for Picasa, one for Facebook) so you would have a bunch duplicates on your PC.

I think the developers could fix that with a one line code change... so if you go here: https://socialfolders.zendesk.com/entries/21039996-follow-junctions-symbolic-links and vote for it, maybe the guys will make the mod and we'd all have a really slick way to synchronize our computers+ picasa + facebook.

Answer (score 1):

I've just discovered [Showzey](http://www.showzey.com), which claims to let you manage all your online photos (certainly those stored within Picasa web albums, Facebook and Flickr) in one place. It doesn't seem to automatically sync (so doesn't quite meet the requirements in the question) and seems a tad slow to me, but may well be worth a look as a central point for managing what gets shared with whom, across several platforms.